# How to get content of httpWebresponse in proper string form?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpwebresponse, responsestream

Sometimes I am getting kind of garbled response from several web sites.

Here is my code:

```
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
buffer = new Byte[256];//
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
   outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   //resp=resp+ .UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   resp=resp + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer); //resp is string
}
```

when I request from www.google.co.in I get following characters in resp string:

> ?\b\0\0\0\0\0??}y?F?????????Z??????{7m???oX?\r?Y???33??d;y????n?0?

How should I overcome this problem? Is it related to encoding?

Comment: Please, edit your question your self. Its highly difficult to understand it. And select a content or code and click on  `{}` to represent your codes or some special content.

Comment: @kalyan is the question understandable now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [encoding issues with content in response from HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103708/encoding-issues-with-content-in-response-from-httpwebrequest)

Comment: @V4Vendetta i tried it but still i receive the above characters(i.e.??) when i use the url: www.google.co.in i dont know why??? Can you suggest something else???

Comment: @purvang do you referred to the links which I have posted?

Comment: @kalyan yes i reffered to those links but i just found the answer the response was compressed so i had to decompress it!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sockets in C#: How to get the response stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523930/sockets-in-c-how-to-get-the-response-stream)

Answer (score 6):

The response I received was GZip-compressed, so I just decompressed the response stream as shown below:

```
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
```

now one can read the stream using the code I provided above.

@Kalyan Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [How to use the GetResponseStream method in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) and also [Usage of HttpWebResponse and HttpWebRequest](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx) for getting an idea about reading contents from HttpWebResponse. Hope it will help you.